# Static HTML to WordPress migration

Tags: migration

I have a static HTML site (about ten years old) which I am going to migrate to a Wordpress site.

I have used Wordpress before but never as a migration target. From some initial background reading I have come up with the following process to perform the migration:

1. Check hosting provider/package for Wordpress suitability
2. Generate complete current site map
3. Make a complete backup of current site
4. Install Wordpress in subdirectory
5. Install Maintenance mode plugin and activate
6. Migrate content to Wordpress instance (looks like this could be
   painstaking..)
7. Install suitable theme
8. Customise selected theme with Logo/fonts/colours etc.
9. Deactivate maintenance mode
10. Make Wordpress site available from domain root
11. Delete old static html site files

(The migration may take place over several weeks/months so I need the static HTML site to be available until step 10 is completed)

In my naivety are there any pitfalls in the above process, or additional issues I have failed to consider?

Are there any other accepted 'best practices' when performing this kind of migration?

(I originally asked this question [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558953/static-html-to-wordpress-migration) but I guess this is a more appropriate place for such a question)

Comment: Why not just work locally and then you don't have to worry about subdomains/directories, etc?

Comment: There's a plugin for this names something like HTML import 2 http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: This seems like rather solid plan and I don't think you really need external validation here. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. My reasons for not working locally are so I don't have to worry about migrating from local machine to the server when the site is ready, and to enable a few people to view the progress online as the site is being developed. I'm also not aware of a strong reason not to develop a site in this way hence the question...

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the commenter - develop your Wordpress version locally using something like MAMP (if Mac) or WAMP (windows).  In that way, there would be no disruption to your existing site until you are satisfied and ready to upload the Wordpress version.

When you are ready to upload, I would (personally) clear out the whole of the static site (assuming you have backups) and create a fresh installation of wordpress in the root of the site, then upload your theme files, import your database etc.